# What browser uses the least resources?

Tags: browser, cpu-usage, ram

I'm quite fed up from Firefox, Chrome, Opera and all the leading browsers with too much features that I (we) don't even use.
I know there are a lot of browsers out there, open source, minimalistic etc. Can you recommend a good browser that uses the least CPU/RAM? It doesn't need to have a lot of features.

Comment: Depending if you're willing to sacrifice that many features, how about cURL?

Comment: Not cURL. That's sacrificing A LOT of features.
Maybe something like these... http://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/sortname/other_browsers.html

Comment: After a little googling, I found _GreenBrowser_. Can't say if it's any good, but it claims `GreenBrowser is least memory occupy browser`.